# Is it correct and natural to say "I'm writing to know if you could" in emails?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Could you please tell me if it's correct and natural to say *I'm writing to know if you could... in emails*? For example:

> **I'm writing to know** if you could send me the package tomorrow.

If that doesn't sound natural, would you tell me what you would say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm writing to **find out** whether you could...* might fit better. To *find out* means to *come to know*, or to get information about something.

Comment: People often *write* requests like this using relatively roundabout phrasing that they might be less likely to use in a spoken and/or face-to-face interaction. Maybe people have a tendency to ***write** an email to **find out*** about something, but I bet when they're on the phone they're more likely to say *I'm calling to **ask** [about something]*.

Comment: *writing to ask...* works too. *writing to know...* doesn't work so well though.